# Add images over image WP8

Tags: image, windows-phone-8

How can I add pins (images) over an image (a plan like image not map)?  I know that we can use mapoverlay on map but how can I do the same on image?
help please

Comment: Add an element like a canvas on top of the image, and add your pins to that canvas?

Comment: I ve tried this solution but I have an issue with the positions: my Plan image is 6000X5000 and my Canvas 480X800

Comment: You'll need to move and scale the position of the pins based on the underlying image. **That's a REALLY large image.** I'm a bit surprised that your app isn't crashing given it could be about 90MB uncompressed in memory.

Comment: I am using the SDK Nokia imaging.